# Data Compare feature missing in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I cannot find Data Compare in Visual Studio 2012. Schema compare is there.

Was it removed? Or is it hidden somewhere?

Comment: I can't find this feature either.  However, the schema compare looks nicer.

Comment: Can't find it in the released version either

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Someone already opened up a [ticket on Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729093/visual-studio-11-data-comparison-feature-missing) for this. The answer from Microsoft as of 3/13/2012 was that they have not yet implemented the feature in the new SQL Server Data Tools used by Visual Studio 11, but that they plan to add it in the future.

The work around is to use the VS 2010 data compare.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid they'd scrape this feature.

Comment: It seems like it's also gone from VS 2010 in Windows 8... Weird.

Comment: look at the next answer, finally here in the data tools update

Comment: Please download SQL Server Data Tools from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015 to have the Data Compare feature (source: @Garry English's response below)

Answer (score 35):

You can install it with the SQL Server Data Tools - June 2013 update

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015

Answer (score 4):

Also take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx. This "seems" to be replacing the data tools that came with Visual Studio 2010 and is how updates are being distributed.

Also waiting for data compare!!

Chuck

Answer (score 2):

If you are going against SQL Server 2012, the workaround from VS2010 Data Compare will not work. VS2010 Data Compare only seems to work on SQL 2008R2 (and maybe on older versions too)

Answer (score 1):

You need to download `SSDT` to compare sql server data. It's does not came with visual studio. However you can also use [Master Data](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/530c546a-fdd3-4589-b2b2-e3c4aab13fba) `visual studio addin` to compare `sql server databases` .. It's `lightweight(1mb)` and also includes some advance feature over `SSDT` ..